# PSQL: Full text search to ignore or match periods and stop characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, full-text-search

I have a full-text search running fine using `tsvector` / `tsquery`:

```
to_tsvector('simple', text) @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', :query)
```

I am formatting the query to include partial matches:

```
{ query: `${searchTerm}:*` }
```

However, if I search for `'node'` it does not match against text that contains `'node.js'`.

How can I include partial matches that have a period or other similar stop character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appending `:*` to the search term and then passing it to plainto_tsquery doesn't make any sense, as plainto_tsquery just strips the `:*` back off again.  You would need to either use to_tsquery, or just write the query directly. For example,

```
select to_tsvector('simple', 'node.js') @@ 'node:*'::tsquery;
```

yields true.